# Derivative of an Integral operator, Gateaux derivative

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, frechet-derivative

let $$T:(C([0,1]),\lvert \lvert . \rvert\rvert_\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R, \ f \rightarrow \int_0^1f(s)^2 \,ds $$

**$(i)$** Calculate the directional derivative of $T$ in direction $g \in C([0,1])$ and point $f \in C([0,1])$

**$(ii)$** What difference it makes, if we change the norm $\mid \lvert.\rvert\rvert_\infty$ with another norm?

For (i) i tried to use $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {1}{t} . \left(T(f+gt)-T(f)\right)$$

so i did :

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {1}{t} \left(\int_0^1 f+gt(s)^2\,ds- \int_0^1 f(s)^2\,ds)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {1}{t} \left(\int_0^1 f(s)^2 \,ds+ \int _0^1 gt(s)^2\,ds- \int_0^1 f(s)^2\,ds\right)$$ $$=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {1}{t}\left(\int _0^1 t\cdot g(s)^2\,ds\right)$$
$$= \int _0^1 g(s)^2\,ds$$

- Is it correct, what i did here?
- Does it make any difference if we change the **norm** as in **(ii)** ? I think it does not make any difference because $\int_0^1g(s)^2\,ds \in \mathbb R$ so it is not important what the norm of $C([0,1])$ is. But i am not sure !!

Comment: How do you go from the first to the second line? And how from the second to the third?

Comment: $(f+tg)^2 \ne f^2 + (tg)^2$

Comment: @G.Chiusole 1. $\int f+g = \int f + \int g$ and then  2. $\int f - \int f =\int f +(- \int f) = \int f - f = \int 0 = 0$ What do u think?

Comment: @daw Than how could i do it? would you please show me how would you do it?

Comment: just correctly square all these expressions, then the calculation is almost the same. For start, use brackets at the correct places $\int (f(s))^2 ds$.

Comment: Also what is $gt(s)$ ?? $t$ is a number.

Comment: @daw i guess it should be $(t*g(s))^2$ or i am compeltly wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compute the Gateaux derivative, note that for any $f,g \in C[0,1]$ we have

\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} (T(f+ tg)-T(f)) &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^1 (f + tg)^2(s) ds - \int_0^1 f^2(s) ds \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^1 f^2(s) + 2 t f(s) g(s) + t^2 g^2(s) - f^2(s) ds \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^1 2 t f(s) g(s) + t^2 g^2(s) ds \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^1 2 t f(s) g(s) ds + \int_0^1 t^2 g^2(s) ds \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 f(s) g(s) ds + \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} t \underbrace{\int_0^1 g^2(s) ds}_{< \infty} \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 f(s) g(s) ds + 0 \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 f(s) g(s) ds = 2 \langle f,g \rangle_{L^2}
\end{align}

Regarding the Gateaux derivative, I am not sure what difference should occur when the norm is changed, since Gateaux derivative only depends on the norm on the target - here $(\mathbb{R}, \vert \cdot \vert)$.

However, it may have an influence on the existence of the Frechet derivative.